# Find the $8^{\text{th}}$ root of $1$ in the form $x+iy$.

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

I have squared each side $3$ times (not sure on the correct word but made it so it's $1=(x+iy)^8$ and expanded, is this the answer or is there a step to simplify everything?

Comment: Are you familiar with polar representations of complex numbers, e.g. $z=r e^{i \theta}$?

Comment: What do you mean by *the* 8th root? It is not unique.

Comment: That _sounds_ right, but could you show your answer? That would make it easier to be sure what you have is what the problem expects. (Note that $1+0i$ is a solution too, but very probably not what you're supposed to answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A square root of $1$ is $-1$. A square root of $-1$ is $\mathrm i$. And $\mathrm i=\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\pi/2}$ hence a square root of $\mathrm i$ is $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\pi/4}$, which you might know as $z=(1+\mathrm i)/\sqrt2$.

*Exercise:*

- Check that $z^8=1$.
- Explain why the word "the" does not appear in the paragraph above.
- Find **the** seven other eighth roots of $1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$1^{1/8} = e^{2\pi ik/8}, ~~k = 0,1,\dots7$$

Because of the identity

$$e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$$
The $8$ solutions in $\Bbb C$ to $z^8 = 1$ are
$$\cos(2\pi k/8) + i \sin (2\pi k/8)~~~k = 0,1,\dots7$$